# Give an example of a non-self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$ whose range is $H$ and which is not invertible.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Give an example of a non-self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$ whose range is $H$ and which is not invertible.

I cannot think of an example to save my life. Any solutions/hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the rank nullity theorem, any $H$ with such a map must be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Think about left and right shift!

Answer (score 2):

The canonical example would be the reverse shift on $\ell^2 (\mathbb N) $. That is, the operator  $T $ given by $$T (a_1,a_2,\ldots)=(a_2,a_3,\ldots). $$

Answer (score 0):

How about the shift map on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: How do you define it for $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @Freeze_S Oops.  Typo.  I intended $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, just as the answer above me.  Didn't want to totally give it away though.

Comment: Do you know `\ell` which gives "$\ell$"?

Comment: @Freeze_S Just saw that!  I do not deal with these spaces on a daily basis, so it has never really come up for me.